# Swift PrepareForSegue EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: xcode, swift, ios7

I have a runtime error: *Thread 1: EXC_BreakPoint(cod=EXC_I1386_BPT,subcode=0x0)*

I did not set any breakpoint inside Xcode. From the debugger,error is due to PrepareForSegue that stops a thread "swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional"

**BarTableViewController1 Class**

```
    @IBAction func solve_PressedBar(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SolveBar", sender: sender)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue ( segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "SolveBar") {
            var svcBar = segue.destinationViewController as BarTableViewController2

            for items in textField1 {
                length.append((items as NSString).floatValue)
            }

            for items in textField2 {
                youngMod.append((items as NSString).floatValue)
            }

            for items in textField3 {
                diameter.append((items as NSString).floatValue)
            }

            for items in textField4 {
                forceBarWall.append((items as NSString).floatValue)
            }

            self.funcForceBarWall()

            println("variables are from TableViewController2")
            println(self.length)
            println(self.youngMod)
            println(self.forceBarWall)
            println(self.diameter)

            svcBar.length2 = self.length
            svcBar.youngMod2 = self.youngMod
            svcBar.diamter2 = self.diameter
            svcBar.forceBarWall2 = self.forceBarWall

            println("testing from bar viewcontroller1")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look here first:

```
var svcBar = segue.destinationViewController as BarTableViewController2
```

Check your storyboard and make sure that the segue does connect to a BarTableViewController2 item.  Sometimes when dragging, I connect the segue to something else accidentally.

Comment: Thanks man. I've been trying to fix this bug for 3 days.. Such a careless mistake!